# Dividing the page into 2 sections using flexbox

Tags: css, comparative-review

I want to have a layout for desktop screens, so mostly wide screens with 4:3 or 16:9 aspect ratio.

The layout is made out of 2 sections: right and left. The left section takes 2/3 of the width and the right section should take the remaining 1/3 of the width.

I have 2 options but I am not sure which one is better, or if there's a better way completely., maybe using Grid

Below a demo for the two options. Note that you need to open in full screen because from some reason in the second option it stack the items even though the width is set. (So not sure why it can't handle this width on smaller widths)

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.left_section {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}

.right_section {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.left_section_option_two {
  flex: 1 1 66%;
}

.right_section_option_two {
  flex: 1 1 33%;
}

.flex-item {
  background: deeppink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item_option_two {
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item left_section">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item right_section">2</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item_option_two left_section_option_two">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item_option_two right_section_option_two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think about what happens when someone hits CMD + a few times in their browser to improve font readability. The fixed `line-height: 100px;` seems weird, in that context. Consider phrasing it in terms of `em`.

Comment: thank you, I will!